# Button to expand the length of element above

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, width

This is a striped down version of my code but will suffice. I want my button to expand the length of the control above it.

[image]

i want the button to expand the length of control on top. My markup goes here....

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-inline row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
                   </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-7 col-md-pull-1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-1 col-md-pull-1">
                        <select id="displayTypeList">
                            <option>List Only</option>
                            <option>List and Photos</option>
                            <option>Photos Only</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                     </div>
                <div class="form-inline row">
                 <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-7 col-md-pull-1">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-1 col-md-pull-1">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="btnSearch" class="btn-block" >Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
```

Comment: Please add width:100% to #displayTypeList and #btnSearch, so the two controls will expand exactly how big is the column.

Comment: so i did and it made the displaytypelist shorter which i dont want i want to expand the search button instead

Comment: Is it okay if you add it only to #btnSearch?